# Apache ProxyPass - Regex to Exclude Files

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, load-balancing, proxypass

I'm trying to exclude all files starting with **"dgg-"** and ending in **".xml"**, example: **dgg-file-1.xml** from using the apache proxy.

**This works:**

```
ProxyPass /myfile.xml ! # single file
ProxyPass /directory ! # all files inside dir
```

**This doesn't work:**

`ProxyPass /dgg-(.*)\.xml !`

**How can I achieve this ?**

ps- I'm using this code inside the `httpd.conf->virtualhost` **not** `.htaccess`.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? What else is in the file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `ProxyPassMatch`. `ProxyPass` expects fully written path elements, it does not accept regexes.

As `ProxyPassMatch` takes a regex, this means you must also anchor it:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/dgg-[^.]+\.xml$ !
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a situation where I wanted few images to be picked from Apache webserver and few images to be included from the application server (In my case Jboss).
So I wanted one regex that had to both exclude and  include. Here is what I added to httpd.conf file under VirtualHost tag.

There are some css and js files which are in jsf jars and jenia popup jars which we
will not find on webserver. So reach out to app server.The regexp is looking for all   *.js  and *.css urls  but exclude any urls that have /jenia4faces and /faces in it. This is to make sure scripts like this /MYWEBAPP/jenia4faces/popup/popupFrame/js/popupFrame.js  and /MYWEBAPP/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/tabbedpane.HtmlTabbedPaneRenderer/11302665/dynamicTabs.js  are still pulled from app server . Rest all .js and .css will be served by webserver.

```
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/MYWEBAPP/(?!jenia4faces).*\.js)$ !
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/MYWEBAPP/(?!faces).*\.css)$ !
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/MYWEBAPP/(?!jenia4faces).*\.js)$ !
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/MYWEBAPP/(?!faces).*\.css)$ !
```

where /MYWEBAPP  is my web apps root context.
Also (?!faces) is to tell if the url doesnt not have "faces" in the url path.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! 

I'm using Apache 2.4 with php5-fpm and a ProxyPassMatch to fcgi. However, excluding a folder from being passed was proving increasingly frustrating. After searching some time for a solution, this finally did the trick. Just in case someone else needs to see how it works together (e.g. for a Drupal installation where the files folder should not allow php execution):

`ProxyPassMatch ^(/sites/default/files/(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ !`
`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:8000/var/www`
`AddHandler php5-fcgi .php`